# Access to main form from a thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I'm trying to write some Text (that I read on an other thread) in a `TextBox` on the main Form.

I'm having a bit of trouble in doing that.
I tried with get/set of `txtBox.Text` but is not working.

Here is my MAIN code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Worker w;
    public volatile bool running = true;
    public string KBox
    {
        get { return txtK.Text; }
        set { txtK.Text = value; }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        KBox = "TEST";             // It works
        w = new Worker();
        Thread kThread = new Thread(w.readLogs);
        kThread.Start(0);
        trdList.Add(kThread);
    }
}
```

Here the Thread:

```
public class Worker : Form1
{
    public Worker(){ }

    public void stopProcess()
    {
        running = false;
    }

    public void readLogs(object type)
    {
        string filename;
        while (running)
            {
                this.SetText((int)type, running.ToString());
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
    private void SetText(int type, string txt)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case 0:
                KBox += Environment.NewLine + txt;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Looking at `KBox` in debugging I see that it takes the value, so I think that the thread set it correctly, but the `TextBox` have problem with that.

I think that should be something similar to `Volatile` but volatile doesn't work for get/set.

The problem is that the `TextBox` still is blank.

Comment: What is the problem? You get `InvalidOperationException`?

Comment: I already saw that example, and tried with Invoke but the Thread is in an other class and the txtK.Text = value will not works, also if set as protect or public

Comment: The problem is that the textbox still blank

Comment: Instead of mark it as duplicated (that is not true) HELP ME.

Comment: Where do you set `running` field to true?

Comment: at the declaration: public volatile bool running = true; Anyway that is not the issue, the varaible KBox collect all infos, but the textBox don't print it

Comment: Ok where did you show the Worker form? You're not showing it anywhere.

Comment: Worker doesn't have a form, the form is in the Main Class

Comment: Try calling Application.DoEvents() after setting the text

Comment: After reading your last comment I see that your concept is wrong. You must pass ´this´ to the Worker instance and set it's textbox as described in the duplicate question

Comment: Then `Worker` shouldn't inherit from `Form1`. It should just inherit from `System.Object` and pass the instance `this` as @VladL says. Then call `form1Instance.KBox += Environment.NewLine + txt;` Also you need to refer the duplicate question to see how to update UI from another thread.

Comment: Ok solved passing the `Form1` instance and calling the textBox with Invoke.
Thanks a lot :)